# How to exit out of a Python Menu into another directory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a python driven menu and one of the options is to list the directory and then I would like it to then exit the menu into that directory that was listed. However, once it exits, I'm back in the directory the script ran from.

How can I do this?  I'm still a n00b at Python scripting so take it easy on me ;).

```py
import os

print("\t-------------------------------------------------")
while True:
    print("""
        1. List then exit into directory
        2. Exit  
      -------------------------------------------------""")
    ch=int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    
    if (ch == 1):
        os.system("cd /data/volumes/stuff/")
        os.system("ls -l | more")
        exit()
  
    elif ch == 2:
        print("Exiting application")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")

    input("Press enter to continue")
    os.system("clear")
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears as though you want to `break` out of the while loop and **not** `exit` the code.

So you can do this:

```py
import os

print("\t-------------------------------------------------")
while True:
    print("""
        1. List then exit into directory
        2. Exit  
      -------------------------------------------------""")
    ch=int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    
    if (ch == 1):
        os.system("cd /data/volumes/stuff/")
        os.system("ls -l | more")
        break
  
    elif ch == 2:
        print("Exiting application")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")

    input("Press enter to continue")
    os.system("clear")
```